# Is there a way to call PowerPoint's DoEvents() function from a C# addin?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I'm trying to add a constant loop running in the background on a C# PPT addin. Since I don't want it to cause PowerPoint to lag I'd like to replicate the DoEvents functionality that VBA provides

What I'm trying to do looks similar to this: The idea here would be for the code to print a new line every second while PowerPoint keeps functioning normally.

This code runs properly at first, however it doesn't solve the problem I was trying to solve as it will freeze PowerPoint whenever any event is sent  (such as MouseUp) even without any Method listening to the event in the code.

```
int seconds = 0;
time = DateTime.Now.Second + 1;

while (true)
{

    if (DateTime.Now.Second >= time)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(seconds + " seconds have passed since the addin started");
        time = DateTime.Now.Second + 1;
    }

    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
}
```

I tested the approach directly inside powerpoint's VBA engine and it works as intended (Note: 1/86400 is equivalent to adding a second to Ms Office dates)

```
Sub countTime()

    nextTime = Now + (1 / 86400)
    counter = 0

    Do While True
        If Now >= nextTime Then
            counter = counter + 1
            Debug.Print (counter & " seconds have passed since the start")
            nextTime = Now + (1 / 86400)
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

I can't access PowerPoint's DoEvents method from the C# addin. Is there any way to replicate this?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you get an error at line `Application.DoEvents();`? What does it say?

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clear enough. I get an error saying that application does not contain a definition for DoEvents an no extension method DoEvents accepting a first argument of type Application could be found

Comment: What type is `Application` or is Application the type itself? In your code, DoEvents looks like a static method.

Comment: Since this is a PPT addin Application is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application type object

Comment: It's an interface that allows the addin to access items, methods and information inside the PPT presentation

Comment: Why not just use a timer with an interval of 1 second?  Then you shouldn't need a loop and DoEvents.

Comment: The problem is that while the code runs (either a timer or a loop) PPT doesn't respond to user input, unless adding the DoEvents method. I'm trying to get an addin to run for and undefined timespan and not cause any lag to the user

Comment: When you have access to the System.Windows.Forms namespace you could try `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();`

Comment: I did try this, it removes the error, however it doesn't fix the issue I-m trying to solve as PPT stops running, the same as would happen if I didn't use the DoEvents method at all

Comment: Maybe this helps you: The DoEvents method lies in the `Interaction` VBA module, not in `Application`.

Comment: Ok, the logic was wrong... ```System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();``` works. Since I was only calling it once per second it was causing problems. However it still seems to be causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by simply using a different thread to run the while loop as this doesn't interfere with PowerPoint events and works as intented.

I believe DoEvents, since its being called from a different library than PPT uses internally ends up causing problems, which explains why the code worked until any event (such as MouseDown or MouseUp) was being sent by PowerPoint.

Thanks to everyone who helped me on this!